# multiple check box error in rails with the help of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

In @eyecolor contain hash

```
{"Brown"=>"Brown", "Black"=>"Black", "Blue"=>"Blue", "Green"=>"Green"}.
```

Now i want to show multiple check box in rails, and i have implement this code for this

```
<%= check_boxes_tag "eyecolor[]", options_for_select(@eyecolor, params['eyecolor']),{:multiple => true,:size=>5} %>
```

and i want to check Black

but it didn't show me multiple checkbox, It display me only one check box.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `check_boxes_tag` helper, can you link to some documentation for it please?

Comment: Also, wouldn't your data be better stored in an array?  ie `["Brown", "Black", "Blue", "Green"]`  Using a hash seems redundant if all values are the same as their keys.